# How to access to Recovery Mode in Ubuntu 19.10 (so I can modify Grub)?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.10, nomodeset

I have just installed Ubuntu Studio 19.10 on two computers (Mac) and I completely love it. I only have problems on one of the two. I should add the "nomodeset" in grub file (as I did for the version Ubuntu 18). The problem that I have with Ubuntu Studio 19.10 is: how to enter in the safe mode (recovery mode)? I click left - shift button, at the boot but nothing happens. I have also tried Esc button. If someone could tell me some trick to access to the Safe mode at the boot I would be grateful.

Comment: Try with `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. After you finish run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Yes I wish to try that! But how? Where? The problem is that I can't access to Recovery Mode! The Boot doesn't work! Everytime I try to boot I have this error message: "System BootOrder not found. Initialiting defaults" and after few seconds there is: /dev/sda4: clean, 393542/15106048 files, 4223952/604419328 blocks

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I don't see the solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Right when you press the power button, hold shift.  you will automatically go to grub.  Select the image you want, and select recovery mode.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried but It doesn't work :(

Comment: i see in your post, that you said you pressed the shift key.  did you **Hold** the shift key?

Comment: Yes I have also tried to hold. Message in the screen is: " "System BootOrder not found. Initialiting defaults."

Comment: I would think that `system bootorder not found. initializing defaults` means that it cannot find a bootable device.  try entering your BIOS to make sure your boot devices are connected.

Comment: I am using Mac, I don't think there is any bios. The problem would be fixed if I could modify the Grub (entering "nomodeset")

Comment: Press and hold CMD, OPT, “O” and "F" to get to your BIOS

Answer (score 0):

- **If you can enter the grub:**

  1. press <kbd>c</kbd> into commandline.
  2. type:

```
> set root='hd0,msdos6' (change to your own partition)
> linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic(your own version)  root=UUID=(your own UUID)    ro recovery nomodeset
> initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic(your own veriosn)
> boot
```

`ls` and `cat` work.
Several files that indicates partition UUIDs:

```
(hdx,msdosx)/boot/grub/grub.cfg (Actually the recovery mode boot code I copied is inside)
(hdx,msdosx)/etc/fstab
```

- **If you can't enter the grub:**
  use a livecd

Answer (score 0):

I solved creating a small partition and installing Xubuntu 18. With that I resolved the issues of the Ubuntu 19.10. Now everything works fine.